# Deadlock : Net installer asks to close invoked application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have this scenario.
I am installing an application through a custom installer application(.NET application).
Since the application requires atleast .NET4, there is a check in the custom installer to see if it is already installed.
In case it is not already installed, the custom installer attempts to install .NET4 through a batch file.
The problem here is when the .NET4 installation is going on, it throws a dialog saying "The following applications should be closed before continuing with the setup : Custom installer"
i.e The .NET installation is asking to close the application which invoked it.
What should i do to avoid this deadlock?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Just close it, install .NET and then try your installation again.

Comment: I have to do it from the installer itself.

Comment: you did not specify it in the question :)

Comment: Well, those are the hidden lines  :)